# Win32com arguments input

Tags: excel, win32com

I can not get Full Address of cell with win32COM in python:

```
cell.Address(external=True) get error while cell.Address only gives string
```

1. How to get config to get full Address of cell ?
 2. I want to do **Formula Evaluate likes in Formula Ribbon** programmatically with Python ? Have anyway to access such features by win32COM ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just found answer:
cell.GetAddress(external=True) - the win32com has .Get for method with arguments.